# Image uploading stuck on "crunching"

Tags: uploads, media-library

I have a problem to upload images to the media library when is used multi-file uploader on WP 3.5.2. Single file media uploader works fine.

I have tested it with 1k PNG image, which was stuck on "crunching" anyway. Debug log for that part came with those messages:

```
[23-Jul-2013 13:41:28] PHP Notice:  has_cap was called with an argument that is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version 2.0! Usage of user levels by plugins and themes is deprecated. Use roles and capabilities instead. in /home/animals/public_html/mysite.com/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2925
[23-Jul-2013 13:41:28] PHP Notice:  has_cap was called with an argument that is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version 2.0! Usage of user levels by plugins and themes is deprecated. Use roles and capabilities instead. in /home/animals/public_html/mysite.com/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2925
[23-Jul-2013 13:41:28] PHP Notice:  get_theme_data is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version 3.4! Use wp_get_theme() instead. in /home/animals/public_html/mysite.com/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2841
```

Also when I try to use Image Uploader from Featured Image it comes with that error message:

```
An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later.
```

Looks like it is WP related issue rather than hosting/permissions. WP_MEMORY_LIMIT is set to 128M, PHP mem limit is same and PHP upload limit is 5M.

As further testing it looks like is related to the Media Library. If I will reset DB and leave all as is it works. When I will re-upload DB with almost 12,000 image it crashes.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)? Try with two very, very small images-- something like 1k. I suspect a files size or other upload limit.

Comment: OP updated with debug info

Comment: Those `Notices` should not be fatal, though the uploader is sensitive. Disable your plugins and switch themes. I doubt the Core is causing those errors.

Comment: I have just tested clean WP install and it works. Looks like some plugin or theme option is messing with it.

Comment: Try to find out which plugin or theme is causing the issue and maybe we can make some progress.

Comment: I have uploaded all on that clean WP install and it works. I think I need to reproduce those steps on that "broken" domain.

Comment: Well, it looks like it is related to the Media Library. If I will reset DB and leave all as is it works. When I will re-upload DB with almost 12,000 image it crashes.

Comment: Diable all plugin and try again. If success then try to locate which plugin is acting up

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok so i'm on wordpress 3.8.1 and i was having this issue and i tried EVERY FIX from every post i could find on this problem of the image upload staying stuck on "crunching" or having it say "image data does not exist"

So apparently if the image dimensions (e.g. 1920x1080) are bigger than what you have set for your "maximum width" and "maximum height" in your Settings > Media, then you will have this issue.

I set my max width to 2200 and my max height to 1300 and now my bigger images upload with no problem!!!

Finally!!!! i hope this helps anyone out there

Answer (score 1):

Try updating file permissions of your WP-content and uploads folder, in most cases this should fix media upload related problems.

Comment: Oye @Tiubles & welcome to WPSE! I second your notion, that upload related problems are often permission related, but if the "Single file media uploader works fine", can that still be the cause of the issue? I doubt it, to be honest. If you hadn't registered 11 minutes, but 11 months ago, I wouldn't have commented, but downvoted - rethink this answer. Does it make sense?

Comment: Permissions are correct. Even tested with 0777.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same problem. After reducing the resolution of image, I was able to upload smoothly.